# Assigning Javascript Object Properties

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a more elegant way of assiging these properties?  This if statement could get ugly by the time I finish all the various scenarios.  I'm also trying to avoid case statements.

```
if(arrResponse.length>2){
    objResponse = {
        type : evl_ResponseType[arrResponse[0]].name,
        partition : evl_Partition_Status_Code[arrResponse[1]].description,
        icons : iconLED(bin(arrResponse[2]).result),
        numeric : arrResponse[3],
        beeps : BEEP_field[arrResponse[4]],
        msg  : arrResponse[5].replace('$','').trim()};
    } 
else {
    objResponse = {
        type : evl_ResponseType[arrResponse[0]].name;
    }
}
return objResponse;
```

Comment: Create object by var objResponse = {};  Then assign properties by objResponse.probName = value;

Comment: The various `evl_` objects are dictionaries, and `arrResponse` contains keys into that dictionary which are being used to look up the actual values you want to hang on to?

Comment: And when you say 'finish all the various scenarios'...can you give an example of what's left? That'll make it easier to find a general pattern.

Comment: How about starting with the basics, like shorter variable names. There's no generic syntax that could possibly fit your very specific scenario. If this is done in a number of places, you may be able to create a helper function. But if this is the only spot, that would be a waste.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind.  I'm still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you *could* do this:

```
objResponse = {
    type : evl_ResponseType[arrResponse[0]].name;
};
if(arrResponse.length>2){
    objResponse.partition = evl_Partition_Status_Code[arrResponse[1]].description;
    objResponse.icons = iconLED(bin(arrResponse[2]).result);
    objResponse.numeric = arrResponse[3];
    objResponse.beeps = BEEP_field[arrResponse[4]];
    objResponse.msg  = arrResponse[5].replace('$','').trim();
} 
return objResponse;
```

But I don't think I'd call it more elegant.

If you don't mind the properties existing even when they don't have useful values, you could do this:

```
objResponse = {
    type : evl_ResponseType[arrResponse[0]].name;
    partition : arrResponse.length>2 && evl_Partition_Status_Code[arrResponse[1]].description,
    icons : arrResponse.length>2 && iconLED(bin(arrResponse[2]).result),
    numeric : arrResponse.length>2 && arrResponse[3],
    beeps : arrResponse.length>2 && BEEP_field[arrResponse[4]],
    msg  : arrResponse.length>2 && arrResponse[5].replace('$','').trim()
};
return objResponse;
```

The properties will have the value `false` if the condition prefixing them isn't met.

That also has the advantage that you can tailor the conditions to the index you're using (e.g., using `arrResponse.length > 5` when you're going to use `arrResponse[5]` for `msg`).

---

Side note: Your code wasn't assigning to `partition` if `arrResponse.length` was not `>2`, but the value you're assigning to `partition` is there even if `arrResponse.length` **equals** `2`.

Comment: Make be make sense to improve readibility by creating functions. For example function getPartition() { return arrResponse.length>2 && evl_Partition_Status_Code[arrResponse[1]].description; } and use it. Little bit more code to write, but then it will be simple to read and understand. I personally prefer to move large amount of code from IF statement to functions and then to use them. Such way I can understand logic without lookign in details. Anyway, upped the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, your response helped.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a shorthand? It looks better while still keeping your current structure true.

```
objResponse = arrResponse.length > 2 ? {
    type: evl_ResponseType[arrResponse[0]].name,
    partition: evl_Partition_Status_Code[arrResponse[1]].description,
    icons: iconLED(bin(arrResponse[2]).result),
    numeric: arrResponse[3],
    beeps: BEEP_field[arrResponse[4]],
    msg: arrResponse[5].replace('$', '').trim()
} : {
    type: evl_ResponseType[arrResponse[0]].name;
}
return objResponse;
```

Comment: "Ugly" is a bit of a subjective thing to say. Wouldn't call it particularly unreadable either, and I'm not the greatest at reading code.

Comment: I personally don't find it ugly nor unreadable. But everyone has their opinions so ill let him have his.

Comment: Ternary operators are good for one line expressions like var c = test ? expression1 : expression2; I can't see any benefits of using it in this code. For me this is an bad idea to use it just because I can. Additionally, most of IDEs highlights IF ELSE keywords for readibility. If you look in large code, this is hard to see that code has IF statement.

Comment: all great comments.  the reason I don't use short hand is because I'm trying to get the hang of things first.  If I ever get to the pro level, then I will definitely shorten things up a lot